# can not import name 'model' from 'app.model'

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have two apps 'user' and 'game' and here is my user/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import related
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser , User, 
 AbstractUser , PermissionsMixin
from .managers import CustomUserManager
from game.models import Game


class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, 
                unique=True, blank=True , null=True,)
    email = models.EmailField( blank=True , null=True , unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True , blank=True)


    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
            db_table = 'user'


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
           related_name="players")
    game = models.ManyToManyField(Game)
    is_verfied = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'team'
```

and here is my game/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import User, Team
from leaga.settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_multiplayer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()


class Tournament(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_team = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    info = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    related_name='tounament_user')
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name='team')
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tournament_game')
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tournament_event')

    # some other code and classes here but unnecessary to mention
```

.
.
.
.
when i run :

```
 python manage.py makemigrations user
```

this is the console log:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/.venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/leaga/user/models.py", line 6, in <module>
from game.models import Game
File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/leaga/game/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from user.models import Team
ImportError: cannot import name 'Team' from 'user.models' (/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/leaga/user/models.py)
```

I tried to delete all .pyc files from my project

also, drop the entire database and create again(i know it's probably not the point but I got angry and I dropped the entire database and recreate it

Comment: Your issue maybe be because you're importing from both files from one to another. Try to import your package only before its use.

Comment: It looks like you defined a *circular* import.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem can you please explain more what should I do now? what is the exact place of the problem?

Comment: For me it was because `gunicorn` didn't get reloaded on the production server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/leaga/user/models.py", line 6, in
>
> from game.models import Game
>
> File "/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/leaga/game/models.py", line 3, in
>
> from user.models import Team
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Team' from 'user.models' (/Users/amir/Desktop/leaga/leaga/user/models.py)

From the message we can see that this is due to circular imports.

`user/models.py` tries to import the `Game` model from `game/models.py`, and `game/models.py` tries to import the `Team` model from `user/models.py`.

---

One solution is to remove:

```
from game.models import Game
```

From `user/models.py`, and change:

```
game = models.ManyToManyField(Game)
```

To:

```
game = models.ManyToManyField('game.Game')
```

---

You might want to read: [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) and [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield).

Relevant part copied here:

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself: